# Data Manipulation in R - Manipulating Subsets within subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a large data frame containing data that looks like this:

```
customer    usage   hour    day temp
5           0.13    07      14  59
5           0.12    07      14  51
5           0.11    08      14  53
5           0.19    09      15  56
12          0.19    07      15  60
12          0.13    07      14  50
12          0.13    07      14  40
9           0.16    08      03  47
9           0.16    08      15  59
9           0.17    08      15  53
```

What I want to do is, for each customer, add up their usage for each hour and average their temp for each hour, separated by days. In other words, within each subset of customers, I want a 'usage' sum and a 'temp' average for each hour and each day. So for this sample code, the ideal output would be

```
customer    SumUsage    hour    day Averagetemp
5           0.25        07      14  55
5           0.11        08      14  51
5           0.11        09      15  56
12          0.19        07      15  60
12          0.26        07      14  45
9           0.16        08      03  47
9           0.33        08      15  56
```

I hope this makes sense. I'm new to R and I can't seem to get it to work right. Just to reiterate what I wanted out of the output one more time: Each customer has multiple 'usage' outputs multiple times per hour, on multiple days out of a month. There is also a 'temp' reading for each 'usage' output. I want to combine all the like hour readings per customer. So for each customer for each day, every hour of the day should have a sum of 'usage' outputs for each hour, along with the average 'temp' for all those outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarise` from `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(customer, day, hour) %>% 
  summarise(SumUsage = sum(usage), Averagetemp = mean(temp))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(SumUsage = sum(usage), 
                 Averagetemp = mean(temp)), by = list(customer, day, hour)]
```